# Dealing with many resolves in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I have run into the issue where half my controller dependencies are resolves and I end up with 7-8 parameters after services are injected.

Resolve:

```
resolve{

     first_data:function(){},
     second_data: function(){},
     third_data: function(){}


}
```

Controller:

```
function homeCtrl(first_data, second_data, third_data, ModalService, $state, $timeout, homeService, dataService){

})
```

Is there a way to put all of the resolves into a single parameter?

Comment: Is it possible to encapsulate first - third_data in one object?
Is it always the same data?

Comment: It's a combination of different data for different pages. Are you saying I should put them all under one resolve function and do a $q.all()?

Answer (score 0):

How about `$q`?

```
let promises = [promiseAlpha(), promiseBeta(), promiseGamma()];

$q.all(promises).then(values => {
    console.log(values[0]); // value alpha
    console.log(values[1]); // value beta
    console.log(values[2]); // value gamma

    complete();
});
```

or even:

```
let promises = {
    alpha: promiseAlpha(),
    beta: promiseBeta(),
    gamma: promiseGamma()
}
$q.all(promises).then(values => {
    console.log(values.alpha); // value alpha
    console.log(values.beta); // value beta
    console.log(values.gamma); // value gamma

    complete();
});
```

Credits: http://www.martin-brennan.com/using-q-all-to-resolve-multiple-promises/

The question is? Is the `first_data` http call? If so, use above solution.
If `first_data` is some container with data, just move it to the `service`, and call this service wherever you want, for example:

**service.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .service('DashboardService', DashboardService);

    DashboardService.$inject = ['$http'];

    function DashboardService($http) {

        var _this = this;

        _this.first_data = function () {
            return [{id: 1, content: "some data"}];
        };

        return _this;
    }

}());
```

**controller.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('DashboardCtrl', DashboardCtrl);

    DashboardCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'DashboardService'];

    function DashboardCtrl($scope, DashboardService) {

        var _this = this;

        _this.first_data = DashboardService.first_data;
    }
}());
```